# How to optimize a table in angular material

Tags: html, angular, typescript, entity-framework

im trying to show a list of products, and it does, but the problem is it freeze for 6 or 8 seconds, tha size of the register is 2338, im using entity framework to obtain the register, some idea to solve or optimize

this is the method to get the list from the other class and  there i obtain from the entity framework

```js
   
getProveedor(){
   
   this.apiproveedor.getProveedor().subscribe(response=>{
    
     console.log(response.data);
    if(response.exito==1){
      this.lst=response.data;
      this.resultsLength=this.lst.length;
      
      this.dataSource=response.data;
    }
     
      
   });
   

   
   getProveedor():Observable<Response>{
      
      return this._http.get<Response>(this.url);
      
    }
  this is the html, im using a mat table
```

```html
<!--
-->
<div>
    <mat-toolbar >
        <span >Pharmacy Lion</span>
        
        <img src="./assets/img/2.png" class="tama">
        
    </mat-toolbar>        

    <div>
        <a mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openAdd()">Nuevo Producto</a>
    </div>
    
    
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
<mat-label>Filter</mat-label>

    <input matInput  placeholder="Buscar Nombre" #input (keyup)="applyFilter($event)">


</mat-form-field>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="lst" class="table"
    matSort matSortActive="created" matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="desc">

    <ng-container matColumnDef ="IdProducto"  class="header-align-right" 
    mat-sort-header disableClear>
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header  >#</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.idProducto}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef ="Nombre" >
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header class="header-align-right" >Nombre Producto</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="header-align-right">{{element.nombre}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef ="Cantidad">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="header-align-right"> Cantidad </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="header-align-right">{{element.cantidad}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef ="Descripcion">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="header-align-right">Descripcion</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="header-align-right">{{element.descripcion}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef ="Precio">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="header-align-right">Precio</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="header-align-right">{{element.precio}}</td>
    </ng-container> 
    
   

    
    
    <ng-container matColumnDef ="Acciones">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  class="header-align-right margencab" >Acciones</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="header-align-right ">
            <button (click)="Edit(element)" mat-raised-button color="primary" class="margencab">Editar</button> 
            <button (click)="delete(element)" mat-raised-button color="Basic" class="margencab">Eliminar</button>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="Columnas"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns Columnas"></tr>
    
    
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: for large dataset, you should use pagination. Instead of getting all the data at once you can implement pagination and get data chunk by chunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implementing server side pagination. You need to send page size and page number along with your existing query parameters. In this way it will be more scalable no matter how many data you have cause you are dealing with small chunk of data each request.

you can find a lot of examples out there. With a quick search I found [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/server-side-pagination-using-aspnet-core-and-angul) one that seems easier to understand

Answer (score 2):

You could try implementing lazy loading of data, which is mentioned in material docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to implement `virtual-scroller` provided by material angular CDK (Common Development Kit).
You can find the details [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview).